# Laravel vhosts setup in xampp is working for only first page

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am working with laravel project. It works fine with php artisan. When I setup vhosts it's working only index page(Welcome page) but when I click on login,signup or any other pages it's not working. It shows page not found.

My `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/my_laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev  
    ServerAlias laravel.dev            
    ErrorLog "logs/laravel.log"
    CustomLog "logs/custom.laravel.log" combined
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/my_laravel/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my `hosts file`

```
127.0.0.1 laravel.dev
```

`.htaccess` file inside public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: `.dev` is not available now. Please change to `.local`

Comment: @GiangD.MAI thanks for reply, it's working for welcome page, but its not working for other pages like login,signup etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define URL rewrite in the public/.htaccess File.
Check if you have the correct settings there.
The Laravel default File looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Just backup your .htaccess and try to copy paste this to your htaccess file and check if it works. If you use Laravels Authorization you also have to add this

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Maybe you also have to turn on the Modules `mod_rewrite.c` and `mod_negotiation.c` if they arent already.
You can do this by search and uncomment the line for the desired module in `apache\conf\httpd.conf`

If you want to customize your .htaccess for what ever reason there are many ressources available on the web.

Comment: thaks for your answer, please check my .htaccess file above I have edited my question.

Comment: I don't have idea about .htaccess file management can you please guide.

Comment: Thanks a lot I replaced with .htaccess code with your code. It worked thaks man:)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Now im finally able to write comments :) Im glad that it works for you.